WatermelonDB Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked when switching from LokiJSAdapter to SQLiteAdapter with Node.js
I creted a basic Node.js app with WatermelonDB and LokiJSAdapter and is working fine but when I switched to SQLiteAdapter this error start appering. Any ideas hoe to fix that?
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Myapp\myDB.db'
    at Object.unlinkSync (node:fs:1871:11)
    at Database.unsafeDestroyEverything (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\sqlite-node\Database.js:95:12)
    at DatabaseDriver.unsafeResetDatabase (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\sqlite-node\DatabaseDriver.js:194:19)
    at DatabaseDriver.setUpWithSchema (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\sqlite-node\DatabaseDriver.js:65:10)
    at DatabaseBridge.setUpWithSchema (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\sqlite-node\DatabaseBridge.js:56:12)
    at SqliteNodeDispatcher.call (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\makeDispatcher\index.js:18:12)
    at SQLiteAdapter._setUpWithSchema (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\index.js:138:22)
    at C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\index.js:93:16
    at C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\makeDispatcher\index.js:19:14        
    at DatabaseBridge.initialize (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\sqlite-node\DatabaseBridge.js:40:9) {
    at C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\index.js:93:16
    at C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\makeDispatcher\index.js:19:14        
    at DatabaseBridge.initialize (C:\Myapp\node_modules\@nozbe\watermelondb\adapters\sqlite\sqlite-node\DatabaseBridge.js:40:9) {
  errno: -4082,
  code: 'EBUSY',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'C:\\MyApp\\myDB.db'
} 

I'm checking the connection directly with 'const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath)' the open param is false.
